# im having a problem with a function that transcribes strings

Tags: python, function

I don't understand what is going wrong with this function.

```
def one_dna_to_rna(c):
    """Converts a single-character c from DNA nucleotide
       to complementary RNA nucleotide
    """
    if c == 'A':
        return 'U'
    elif c == 'C':
        return 'G'
    elif c == 'G':
        return 'C'
    elif c == 'U':
        return 'A'
    else:
        return ''


def transcribe(s):
    """Converts a string c from DNA nucleotide
       to complementary RNA nucleotide
    """
    q = 0
    if s == '':
        return ''
    else:
        q = q + one_dna_to_rna(s[0])
        q = q + transcribe(s[1:])
        return q

assert transcribe('ACGTTGCA') == 'UGCAACGU'
assert transcribe('ACG TGCA') == 'UGCACGU'
assert transcribe('GATTACA')  == 'CUAAUGU' 
assert transcribe('')         == ''
```

windows terminal says *TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'*

Comment: ... What problem?

Comment: Why is your `transcribe` function trying to return `p`? What's `p`?

Comment: `one_dna_to_rna` always returns a **string** and you are adding it to `q ` which is an **integer**.

Comment: @Countour-Integral oh. how do i make q a string? or am i just doing it wrong here

Comment: Unless this is homework assignment I would suggest you look at  `str.translate()` and `str.maketrans()` methods

Comment: @buran Or use a dictionary like `return ''.join({'A': 'U', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'}.get(c, '') for c in s)` (I fixed the mapping of T)

Comment: @Matthias, `str.translate` is much faster.

Comment: @buran That might be true, especially because `str.translate` was built to do exactly this task. Anyone willing to do some benchmarking?

Comment: @Matthias, I did - 0.30905784700007644 vs. 2.788803461997304 for 1 mln. calls (translate vs dict solution) translating `'ACGTTGCA'`

Comment: @buran Thanks. I didn't expect a difference by factor 9. Memo to myself: remember `str.translate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You miss the case `c == 'T'` in your `one_dna_to_rna` method
2. Don't initialize `q` to `0`, but to empty string `''`
3. `return p` seems just to be a typo of `return q`

---

Then you can inline the variables in the `transcribe` method

```
def transcribe(content):
   return one_dna_to_rna(content[0]) + transcribe(content[1:]) if content else ''
```

And use a dict is more convenient for the `one_dna_to_rna` method

```
def one_dna_to_rna(c):
    codes = {'A': 'U', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'U': 'A', 'T': 'A'}
    return codes.get(c, "")
```

---

If you knew all the cases (no space char) you could use `str.maketrans` to build a translation to pass to `str.translate`

```
def transcribe(translation, content):
    if s == '':
        return ''
    else:
        return content.translate(translation)

table = str.maketrans('ACGUT', 'UGCAA')
transcribe(table, 'ACGTTGCA')
```

Comment: Hmm, your answer is correct. With this changes the code works. Why was this voted down?

Comment: @mikksu i don't know ;)

Comment: I would create translation table once and pass it as argument to `transcribe`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a list comprehension to pass each character to `one_dna_to_rna`, collect them in a list and return a string of it:

```
def one_dna_to_rna(c):
    """Converts a single-character c from DNA nucleotide
       to complementary RNA nucleotide
    """
    if c == 'A':
        return 'U'
    elif c == 'C':
        return 'G'
    elif c == 'G':
        return 'C'
    elif c == 'U':
        return 'A'
    # added case T!
    elif c == 'T':
        return 'A'
    else:
        return ''


def transcribe(s):
    """Converts a string c from DNA nucleotide
       to complementary RNA nucleotide
    """

    return "".join([one_dna_to_rna(c) for c in s if c])


print(transcribe('ACGTTGCA') == 'UGCAACGU')
print(transcribe('ACG TGCA') == 'UGCACGU')
print(transcribe('GATTACA')  == 'CUAAUGU')
print(transcribe('')         == '')
```

Out:

```
True
True
True
True
```

Answer (score -2):

You set `q = 0` which is of type `int` but should've set `q = ''` (an empty string).

As you add `q + one_dna_to_rna(s[0])` the result of `one_dna_to_rna(s[0])` is going to be a character while `q` is an integer. Python does not know how to add these.

Try

```
def one_dna_to_rna(c):
    """Converts a single-character c from DNA nucleotide
       to complementary RNA nucleotide
    """
    if c == 'A':
        return 'U'
    elif c == 'C':
        return 'G'
    elif c == 'T':
        return 'A'
    elif c == 'G':
        return 'C'
    elif c == 'U':
        return 'A'
    else:
        return ''


def transcribe(s):
    """Converts a string c from DNA nucleotide
       to complementary RNA nucleotide
    """
    q = ''
    if s == '':
        return ''
    else:
        q = q + one_dna_to_rna(s[0])
        q = q + transcribe(s[1:])
        return q

assert transcribe('ACGTTGCA') == 'UGCAACGU'
assert transcribe('ACG TGCA') == 'UGCACGU'
assert transcribe('GATTACA')  == 'CUAAUGU' 
assert transcribe('')         == ''
```